# Recommendation on Charts library (JS / HTML5 / etc)

Tags: charts

I'm looking for a chart library that fulfils most or not all of the requirements:

- Bar charts with support for point labels, and custom labels for X/Y axis, and multiple series.
- Pie charts (simple pie chart)
- Is **responsive** to devices of different screensizes
- Is free for production / commercial use
- Ease of use and reasonable sized support community

Does anyone have any recommendations?
I'm working on data visualization using a Cakephp and PHP environment.

Cheers
Kevin

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is quite a hefty requirement list, but you might find that ZingChart would be a viable candidate.

- Includes bar, pie, and many other chart types.  (http://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/ )
- Multiple series, custom labels for axes (custom labels for anything, really) - http://www.zingchart.com/docs/features/labels/
- Responsive
- Free for production use with a small watermark in the corner and flexible licensing options
- Straightforward, CSS-like syntax
- Plenty of demos in our gallery rand documentation, used by some Fortune 500 companies, and fully supported by our team in San Diego

You’ve probably realized by now that I am with the ZingChart team :-)  We are here to answer any questions you might have.